# How to loop through all object of the same type?

Tags: java, object

For a project I want to check if a `String` is the same as a `String` attribute in one of my objects.

For example, I have 3 item object:

```
Item spotion = new Item("small potion", 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Item mpotion = new Item("medium potion", 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Item lpotion = new Item("large potion", 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I would then want to check if

```
String s = spotion;
```

would equal any of the `Item`'s name (first attribute);

Would there be any way to do this without creating an `ArrayList` of items to loop through but instead just see how many items there are and loop on when created?

Comment: You need a public field or getter in the `Item` class to get to that first attribute.

Comment: `item.name.equals("some string")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: I already have a getter the problem is that I don't know how I would setup a loop for the Items without having to creating an ArrayList where it can loop through.

Comment: You can use streams: `long count = Stream.of(spotion, mpotion, lpotion).filter(item -> item.name.equals(s)).count()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To loop through the objects you would have to put them into an array first, like this:

```
Item[] items = new Item[] {
    new Item("small potion", 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    new Item("medium potion", 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    new Item("large potion", 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
}
```

Then you'd be able to loop through the array using the plain old `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    //your code here
}
```

Or the enhanced for loop:

```
for(Item item : items){
    //your code here
}
```

To compare the variable all you'd have to do is compare the appropriate variable using `equals`:

```
if(item.yourVariable.equals(string)){
    //your code here
}
```

You can't compare the `String` directly to your object unless you override its `toString` method. Instead, you'll have to compare the desired property.

Comment: Just as a side note: When instantiating and assigning arrays directly to a variable the `new Item[]` can be omitted, else a good answer +1 :)